# How can i upload multiple files with sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I want to upload multiple files,this code just select one file for upload

```
const { value: file } = await Swal.fire({
  title: 'Select image',
  input: 'file',
  inputAttributes: {
    'accept': 'image/*',
    'aria-label': 'Upload your profile picture'
  }
})
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true=https%3A%2F%2Fsweetalert2.github.io%2F)

Comment: Your codepen link doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `multiple` to your input

```
const { value: file } = await Swal.fire({
  title: 'Select image',
  input: 'file',
  inputAttributes: {
    'accept': 'image/*',
    'multiple': 'multiple', 
    'aria-label': 'Upload your profile picture'
  }
})
```

Comment: How can we also display all the images? The single file preview is showing but not in multiple.